# "Removes the turnstile navigation for startup." What?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

The below code is provided in the default templates for creating WP8.1 XAML apps. (Universal / WinRT).

What is this code used for?  I can't seem to get a breakpoint to hit when `rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null`.  It could be cool for an app to provide its own opening  animation instead of a turnstile.  E.g. like cortana.

In App.xaml.cs

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                _transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    _transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;
#endif
```

Edit: A clue I found - if all the above code is commented out then turnstile page transitions are everywhere.  Now if only you uncomment: `rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;` then all turnstile page transitions are taken away.  That's weird because ContentTransitions was null before the setter, but transitions are different if the setter is set as null.

Edit Edit: Seems like this code is required due to a OS race condition.  If all the code is commented out except for nulling the ContentTransitions at rare times the app has turnstile animations.

Comment: I look forward to this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (3 Dec 2014)**

I just discovered a way of using animations to 'hide' the OS level turnstile when the app gets loaded the first time.

Three things are required to achieve this -

1. The app doesn't have a splash image.
2. `ContentTransitions` is set to `null` in your main page's `NavigatedTo` handler.
3. Create a `PageIn` animation and animate your main page's `LayoutRoot`'s background color - basically to have it aligned with system background color first and then animate it to whatever color you want in a short amount of time.

You can download a sample from [here](http://1drv.ms/1vlVs80).

---

If you have all the code commented out. You would think that the `ContentTransitions` *should* still be `null` right? At least that's what I thought.

The answer is **no**. The `ContentTransitions` will later be assigned with a `NavigationThemeTransition`.

This might be because in the default `Frame` style, there's these lines of code.

```
<Setter Property="ContentTransitions">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

However, this property of `Frame` only gets set very late. If you put a breakpoint in the constructor of your `MainPage`. You will see it's still `null`. But if you put another breakpoint in the `OnNavigatedTo`, finally you will see both `this.Frame` and `this.Frame.ContentTransitions` with values in them.

What if I uncomment out

```
rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
```

I guess, in the setter of this property, there's no `if (_contentTransitions != null) return;` check, when you set it to `null`, there must be something that stops it from getting the default `NavigationThemeTransition`, and that's why you don't see the turnstile animation anymore.

However, there's still **one animation** you will always see no matter what you do.

Try suspending your app by pressing the **back** or **home** key and re-activate it. Yes, the turnstile animation is back! Though I think this turnstile animation is different from the ones we *disabled* in the `Frame.ContentTransitions`. Take a look at how an app is launched for the very first time - a splash screen coming up with the turnstile animation. This I believe, is the the same one, and it's probably controlled by the OS.

So, why do they put in this check?

```
if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
```

My guess is because since there's an OS level turnstile animation, if you don't provide a splash screen, the OS will simply animate your app launching so it makes sense to skip whatever is inside the `Frame.ContentTransitions`.

You would probably then ask but `Frame.ContentTransitions` is always `null`!

Here's one scenario that it won't be `null`. Try creating a custom `Frame` style with some default `ContentTransitions`, and instead of

```
rootFrame = new Frame();
```

do

```
rootFrame = new Frame { Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["MyFrame"] };
```

This time, you will see the code go into the `if` statement as the `ContentTransitions` is no longer `null`.

Comment: thanks, this is really tricky business.  Still pretty mysterious to me.  Not really sure whether I buy "// Removes the turnstile navigation for startup." is just in case you create a custom frame style.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;`

And replace `rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;`

by `rootFrame.ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection();`

To specify the transition of each Page use:

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition />
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```